# What does catholicism say about inheritance?

Tags: catholicism, inheritance

Are there rules regarding inheritance of property in Catholicism?

For example, can a non-Catholic inherit property from a Catholic according to the Catholic faith?

Comment: Do you mean can a non-Catholic inherit property from his Catholic parents?

Comment: I am unaware of any official rule to prevent this. Church law is of course subject to civil law. New France (Canada), influenced by the Church, made a law that *prevented* children being disinherited unless they married against parental will or left the Church, but this is not the same thing (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:BNKZ334)

Comment: "church law is of course subject to civil law" - there are some who would disagree.

Comment: The meek get it.

Comment: @MattGutting "church law is of course subject to civil law" - try overturning the finding of a civil court just because your church happens to disagree!

Comment: One could argue that one should obey church law in that case.  Civil law would punish you,  of course.  But which to obey?

Comment: @MattGutting All human law should be in-line with divine law.

Answer (score 1):

No there aren't [searched Canon Law, CCC, and Google] and one would expect this to be the case from this particular scripture:

> [Luke 12:13-14 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%2012%3A13-14&version=RSVCE)
>
> **The Parable of the Rich Fool**
>   13 One of the multitude said to him, “Teacher, bid my brother divide the inheritance with me.” 14 But he
>   said to him, “Man, who made me a judge or divider over you?”